# Responsive background image of div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, background-image

I have the following HTML:

```
<body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="page-header">
                <div class="masthead">
                    <div class="header-image"></div>
```

Which is using Bootstrap 3.3.
I want to set a header image which will be used as a banner and will be responsive as much it possible.
I set `header-image`class and I gave it these properties:

```
.header-image {
    background-image: url("../images/amazingimage.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% auto;
    background-position: center;
}
```

But I can't see the image at all.
Please help me, thanks.

UPDATE:
**Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qnsnnf9s/**

Comment: Are you sure your path is even correct? Inspect your elements look up for that png image.

Comment: Set the dimensions for your `div` using `width` and `height`

Comment: @Musk Yes I'm sure...

Comment: can you provide an example? jsfiddle or plunkr?

Comment: @Eun But then it won't be responsive, right?

Comment: @marquez Yes, just a sec...

Comment: @marquez Here is a Fiddle, the imageproperty is the last in the css section http://jsfiddle.net/qnsnnf9s/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`height` and `width` need to be setted.

I also suggest you to use the `background-size: cover` property to scale the image and always fill the available space.

> Scale the background image to be as large as possible so that the background area is completely covered by the background image. Some parts of the background image may not be in view within the background positioning area

```
.header-image {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-image: url("youreimage");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
```

Here the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qnsnnf9s/3/

Comment: Thanks you it works! can you pleas update your answer and change the image url (delete the link to the image because I don;t have the rights to use it)?

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/qnsnnf9s/1/

Heres a slight change to what you wanted. Did you want your navigation to be within the banner image or not?

```
.header-image {
    background-image: url("myimageURL");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% auto;
    background-position: center;
    z-index: 99;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
 }
```

A general rule: Always use pixels when working with heights and always use percentages when using widths. You can't build responsive correctly and efficiently when your working with widths in pixels. Please comment with your answer to the question above and i'll edit the jsfiddle with anything you need changing/updating.

Comment: Thanks it works! just one request: can you pleas remove the background image link? I don't have the rihgts to use it it is just for the sample...

Comment: In your first question your image is saved at '../images/amazingimage.png' just replace the image link with this and you should be fine. I used a image just so you can easily see the change. Just replace it with wherever you've saved your image you wish to use. Any problems, let me know. Goodluck!

Comment: Yes I know but I don't habe the rights to use this specifc image, it was just for the example...

Comment: try to resize the jsfiddle box to the limit you're see that the background will leave blank space in the bottom. That's why i suggested to use `background-size: cover`...

Comment: Yes I was about to edit until I seen you had already commented with the correct changes. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

//CSS BLOCK

```
.header-image {
    height: 500px; //RESPONSIVE USE (%,em, or vh/vw)
    width: 500px; //RESPONSIVE USE (%,em, or vh/vw)
    background: url("../images/amazingimage.png") no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    -webkit-background-position: center center;
}
```